# How to make a Pie Chart with focusable elements in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm looking for some help with creating this UX in Flutter. I have created a mockup in After Effects, please excuse my lack of skills, haven't used AE in a long time!

https://vimeo.com/394465109

I did start creating this with a PanResponder in React Native but it wasn't quite what I need and I am keen to use Flutter.

I have heard that there are some limitations with SVGs in Flutter but it's the only way that I have found to create the layout so far, could also use some advice on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.